# Flash Template Help

Tags: flash, actionscript

Ok, complete Flash noob here, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a flash template that I am working on, and have customized it via the XML files. It's an AS3 template.

I also have a Flash poll script that I am attempting to integrate into the template.

This is where it gets a bit tricky...I have decided to use a modal window (which supports swf files) to open the poll that I am using. If it were as simple as to load the swf file, I would be fine, but the poll also includes XML and PHP files, which I don't know what to do with.

The files included are: preview.swf, preview.fla, the xml file, config.php, edit.php, index.php and then "caurina" and documentation files.

What I'm thinking I need to do is include the preview.swf file into my modal window, but I'm not sure what to do with the rest of these files, do they go into a new folder in the main template folder or what?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

from my point of view this is more an architectural problem than a Flash one. You must consider if you will use / reuse that template in other places ( but you should probably do it anyway )

Create the poll template as a single project, with all the files in the same folder, with it's own namespace: com.andymiller.template.poll, etc...

This may save you a lot of time solving bugs.

If by Caurina you mean a tweener this is a shared class, in this case this won't be necessary, create a lib project or a folder that you know **you won't modify**! If you change the version of any of the libraries this may have "consequences" :)

Hope it Helps